# How handle shifted DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a minor issue in handling `DateTime` in C#. I have designed a windows application that interacts with Harris automation system. The application receives all triggers for EPG programs. Now I have this issue:

> trigger received `DateTime` : 2012-01-31 23:58:23
>
> trigger exact time : `00:03:53` ( this value can be either > now() or < now()

Here is the code that handles this:

```
DateTime segmentStartDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Date;
segmentStartDateTime = segmentStartDateTime +  item.TIME;
```

If we test this code with the case above, I get `segmentStartDateTime = 2012-01-31 00:03:53`, which is the wrong value (the right value should be `2012-02-01 00:03:53`).

I am sure one of you have faced this issue before and I'll appreciate any help to fix this (to determine either the time is in the current day or in the day after).

---

A few more examples:

1)

Input : - Current Time : `2012-03-08 13:27:00` - Received TimeSpan as string : `13:28:30`

Output - The program will start at: `2012-03-08 13:28:30`

2)

Input : - Current Time : `2012-03-08 23:58:19` - Received TimeSpan as string : `00:02:15`

Output - The program will start at: `2012-03-09 00:02:15` (day after)

3)

Input : - Current Time : `2012-03-08 23:58:19` - Received TimeSpan as string : `23:57:43`

Output - The program will start at: Now, it's already time (`2012-03-08 23:57:43`)

Comment: Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`. It's faster and doesn't have issues when changing from/to DST.

Comment: Is the problem that you hoped to get a time on Feb 1st rather than  Jan 31st?

Comment: the issue is i can receive the trigger before its real start datetime

Comment: yes exactely but this is not frequently

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to find the next time it's a certain time-of-day after a given start point?

Comment: of lets take this example, i'am at 23:59:00 and my program receive a trigger with start timespan = 00:05:00, how i can calculate start datetime.

Comment: please don't post the **same** questions more than once.

Comment: What result do you expect for now=`2012-01-31 3:00:00`, time=`01:00:00`? `2012-02-01 1:00:00` or `2012-01-31 1:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime NextTimeOfDayAfter(TimeSpan timeOfDay, DateTime start)
{
  DateTime result = start.Date + timeOfDay;
  if(result<start)
    result=result.AddDays(1);
  return result;
}
```

Not sure how this interacts with DST. But IMO `DateTime` shouldn't be used for local times anyways.

---

Just tested, and both your examples work with my code:

```
var now1=DateTime.Parse("2012-03-08 13:27:00");
var time1=TimeSpan.Parse("13:28:30");
NextTimeOfDayAfter(time1,now1).Dump();//08.03.2012 13:28:30

var now2=DateTime.Parse("2012-03-08 23:58:19");
var time2=TimeSpan.Parse("0:02:15");
NextTimeOfDayAfter(time2,now2).Dump();//09.03.2012 00:02:15
```

---

```
DateTime NextTimeOfDayAfter(TimeSpan timeOfDay, DateTime start, TimeSpan gracePeriod)
{
  DateTime result = start.Date + timeOfDay;
  if(result+gracePeriod<start)
    result=result.AddDays(1);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: i'll make test and i'll give you feedback

Comment: Hi CodeInChaos, but this works only if received timespan is greater than current time. try to test this case :  var now1 = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-08 13:27:00");
            var time1 = TimeSpan.Parse("13:25:30");

Comment: What do you expect for this test case? It will return `2012-03-09 13:27:00` which is the earliest point that's in the future which has that time-of-day.

Comment: no, for this case i expect 2012-03-08 13:25:30 (in my business logic that means that a delay has been occured -trigger has been received in teh past-, in this case i'll send command to start record immediately now), i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Then you need to improve the question. You need to specify a cut-off time. Of far in the past may an event be? You need to clearly explain under which conditions you want a result that's today, but in the past, and when you want a result that's tomorrow.

Comment: @user852194 Even with the third example it's not clear to me. Under which conditions do you decide that it started in the past, and when do you think it's in the future? For example why doesn't your code say that the 2nd example already started >23h ago?

Comment: good question, because there is some offset regarding when triggers can comes ( the triggers can comes 5 minutes before or 5 minutes after the plannified EPG start time) ex : prison break episode 2 will start at 21:12:23, then you should expect trigger in this interval : 21:07:23 until 21:17:23

Comment: but this offset schoudl not be taked in consideration ( customer specification) can be reviewed at any time.

Comment: I've added a variant that allows a grace period. Specify how far in the past the time may be. (Say `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)` or `TimeSpan.FromMinues(5)`

Comment: Really thanks, this was more or less my first idea, since there is no consistent logic in the manner how automation system send triggers, i think your solution is the best one until now, i'll implement it right now

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the DateTimeOffset struct, which was introduced in .NET 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx

(I've never used it myself)